# cstdio stdio.h namespace

Tags: c++, header

I see this line from the c++ reference for `cstdio`:

**Every element of the library is defined within the `std namespace`.**
but I tried the code:

```
std::printf("hello world"); 

printf("hello world");
```

is it true that ***C++ headers puts the names in both the std and the global namespace***?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Including `cstdio` imports the symbol names in `std` namespace and *possibly* in Global namespace.
Including `stdio.h` imports the symbol names in Global namespace and *possibly* in `std` namespace.

The same applies for all c-styled headers.

---

**Reference:**
C++11 standard

**Annex D (normative) Compatibility features [depr]** states:

**D.6 C standard library headers**

> 1 For compatibility with the C standard library and the C Unicode TR, the C++ standard library provides the 25 C headers, as shown in Table 151.

Which include:

> `<assert.h> <float.h> <math.h> <stddef.h> <tgmath.h>`
> `<complex.h> <inttypes.h> <setjmp.h> <stdio.h> <time.h>`
> `<ctype.h> <iso646.h> <signal.h> <stdint.h> <uchar.h>`
> `<errno.h> <limits.h> <stdarg.h> <stdlib.h> <wchar.h>`
> `<fenv.h> <locale.h> <stdbool.h> <string.h> <wctype.h>`

Further on,

> 2   **Every C header, each of which has a name of the form `name.h`, behaves as if each name placed in the standard library namespace by the corresponding `cname header` is placed within the global namespace scope.** It is unspecified whether these names are first declared or defined within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace std and are then injected into the global namespace scope by explicit using-declarations (7.3.3).
>
> 3 [ Example: The header `<cstdlib>` assuredly provides its declarations and definitions within the namespace std. It may also provide these names within the global namespace. The header `<stdlib.h>` assuredly provides the same declarations and definitions within the global namespace, much as in the C Standard. It may also provide these names within the namespace std. —end example ]

Comment: So this is implementation dependent? Interesting, I wasn't aware.

Comment: @MrLister: Yes, and there is no confusion over this the standard clearly states so.

Comment: am I correct that I should prefer to include <cstdio> and that "stdio.h" is "deprecated"?

Comment: @javapowered Officially, yes. Since C++11, the C compatibility headers have been specified in the "Compatibility features" annex of the standard, which describes *"deprecated features, where deprecated is defined as: Normative for the current edition of this International Standard, but having been identified as a candidate for removal from future revisions"*. Labelling them as "identified as a candidate for removal" is arguably perverse, though. http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0619r0.html#3.5 argues that the headers will be retained forever, and should be undeprecated.

Comment: @AlokSave So, which one is preferred, `#include<stdio.h>` or `#include <cstdio>`?

Comment: @John If you intend to use `printf` and `puts`, then stick with `<stdio.h>`. If you are comfortable with always writing `std::printf` and `std::puts` etc., you may choose to use `<cstdio>`.

Answer (score 11):

According to libstdc++ docs:

> The standard specifies that if one includes the C-style header
>   (`<math.h>` in this case), the symbols will be available in the **global
>   namespace** and perhaps in namespace std:: (but this is no longer a firm
>   requirement.) One the other hand, including the C++-style header
>   (`<cmath>`) guarantees that the entities will be found in **namespace std**
>   and perhaps in the global namespace.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt01ch03s02.html

Comment: I think if we use `<cmath>` then it will guarantee that the entities will be available under `namespace std` and hence not in global namespace.

Comment: @KrishnaOza Not true. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71604454/is-it-undefined-behavior-to-use-sqrt-when-including-cmath-as-opposed-to-m).