# Newbie compiler problems

Tags: c, project, getchar

I'm really new in *C* and I have the Code Blocks compiler. When compiling a really simple program. Sometimes it works but sometimes it doesn't. I'm guessing it has something to do with the things I select when starting a new project. I usually select a console application *C* language and I have no idea what to select next  does anyone know whats going on and how to fix it? This is my code:

```
#include <stdio>

int main()
{
  printf ("hello world !");
  getchar ();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you may want to change the include to `<stdio.h>` in `C` or `<cstdio>` in `c++`

Comment: It should be `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: Next time you ask, remember to say exactly which error message you get.

Comment: When posting a question on Stackoverflow, please be specific in your details. Statements such as *"sometimes it doesn't work"*, or *"I still get errors"* don't help. Instead, post the exact error message, and the circumstances under which the compiler emits it.

Comment: The tag `compiler` should be applied to questions concerning the programming of compilers or for questions about the detailed inner workings of compilers. Don't use `compiler` for questions about options and settings for a particular compiler, use the name of the compiler you are interested in instead.

Answer (score 1):

`#include <stdio.h>` and not `#include <stdio>`.

Header files in `C` are saved with `.h` file extension.

Answer (score 0):

headers in C, by convention, end with `.h`.

so it should be `#include <stdio.h>` instead of `#include <stdio>`.

However, if you are using a C++ compiler, with your file being called `foo.cpp`, then you can use `#include <cstdio>` and add `using namespace std;` to use `getchar()` function.

Comment: I do not think `using namespace std;` is required for using `getchar()` - is `getchar()`a part of the std namespace? Also this question is not tagged C++.

Comment: but he is using a C++ IDE(codeblocks), and there is a fair amount of chance he is using a C++ file extension. People often get confused when they try to use an IDE first, for learning. I have to check if getchar recides in std namespace(googling)

Comment: I do not believe its required. - http://ideone.com/CgGNxi

Comment: -1 [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) ... that is awful advice for a beginner and the question is not tagged *C++*.

Comment: By this answer here, it can be implementation dependent @Acme http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460250/cstdio-stdio-h-namespace

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour what if by implementation, `getchar()` does not reside in `std` namespace? Your code will have portability issues.

Comment: If it is `implementation dependent` then its still not advisable.

Comment: why is it not advisable? @Acme and what exactly is not advisable?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour the question was tagged with [tag:C++] in the beginning along with [tag:C]

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I have answered for both C and C++. Not "only" C++.

Comment: And as to WHY I have answered for C++ then see comment #1 on this answer

Comment: @Aniket - regarding _but he is using a C++ IDE(codeblocks)_   Code::Blocks ***is an IDE only***.  _It has no affiliation with any particular type of compiler_, i.e. it will work with many.  I use it all the time (exclusively in fact) with minGW, for ANSI C work.