# Error at program launch

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, mingw, codelite

When I try to launch a program from the Release folder, the OS opens a error window with this message:

Can not find the entry point _gxx_personality_v0 of the procedure in the dynamic link library libstc++.dll

This is the source code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include "tinyxml.h"

using namespace std;

void write_app_settings_doc( )  
{  
    TiXmlDocument doc;  
    TiXmlElement* msg;
    TiXmlDeclaration* decl = new TiXmlDeclaration( "1.0", "", "" );  
    doc.LinkEndChild( decl );  

    TiXmlElement * root = new TiXmlElement( "MyApp" );  
    doc.LinkEndChild( root );  

    TiXmlComment * comment = new TiXmlComment();
    comment->SetValue(" Settings for MyApp " );  
    root->LinkEndChild( comment );  

    TiXmlElement * msgs = new TiXmlElement( "Messages" );  
    root->LinkEndChild( msgs );
    TiXmlElement * deep = new TiXmlElement( "vector" );  
    msgs->LinkEndChild( deep );
    string array[4] = { "Bayer Leverkusen", "Sporting Lisboa", "Villareal", "Montpellier" };
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        TiXmlElement * items = new TiXmlElement( "item" );
        deep->LinkEndChild( items );
        const char* text = array[i].c_str();
        items->SetAttribute("id", i);
        items->LinkEndChild( new TiXmlText( text ));
    }
    msg = new TiXmlElement( "Welcome" );  
    msg->LinkEndChild( new TiXmlText( "Welcome to MyApp" ));  
    msgs->LinkEndChild( msg );  

    msg = new TiXmlElement( "Farewell" );  
    msg->LinkEndChild( new TiXmlText( "Thank you for using MyApp" ));  
    msgs->LinkEndChild( msg );  

    TiXmlElement * windows = new TiXmlElement( "Windows" );  
    root->LinkEndChild( windows );  

    TiXmlElement * window;
    window = new TiXmlElement( "Window" );  
    windows->LinkEndChild( window );  
    window->SetAttribute("name", "MainFrame");
    window->SetAttribute("x", 5);
    window->SetAttribute("y", 15);
    window->SetAttribute("w", 400);
    window->SetAttribute("h", 250);

    TiXmlElement * cxn = new TiXmlElement( "Connection" );  
    root->LinkEndChild( cxn );  
    cxn->SetAttribute("ip", "192.168.0.1");
    cxn->SetDoubleAttribute("timeout", 123.456); // floating point attrib

    doc.SaveFile("appsettings.xml");  
}

void Load() {
    TiXmlDocument *doc = new TiXmlDocument("appsettings.xml"); 
    doc->LoadFile();
    TiXmlElement* root = doc->FirstChildElement("MyApp");
    if (root) {
    TiXmlElement* msgs = root->FirstChildElement("Messages");
    TiXmlElement* input = msgs->FirstChildElement("vector");
    TiXmlNode* child;
    //for (child = input->FirstChild(); child; child = child->NextSibling()) {
    while (child = input->IterateChildren(child)) {
        TiXmlElement* item_element = child->ToElement();
        cout << item_element->GetText() << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    write_app_settings_doc();
    Load();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

CodeLite 5.4
MinGW 4.8.1
Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

You're probably having mismatched `libstdc++6.dll` files

P.S. You can use `#include <cstdio>` not to mix headers (more info about differences [here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460250/cstdio-stdio-h-namespace)

Comment: No, I'm using gnu g++ for the Release

Comment: @user3204810 You can try copying the `libstdc++.dll` to the directory with your binary and see it that works

Comment: I tried to add libstdc++-6.dll inside the Release folder, but the program crash at start

Comment: You probably have another .dll library somewhere causing mismatch problem. Have you installed MinGW only once ?

Comment: No, I have two installation of MinGW

Comment: This may be the problem, as your libstdc++.dll is doubled in system

Comment: @user3204810 what did you do exactly?

Comment: I have remove one of the MinGW installation

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it from within codelite then make sure that mingw 4.8.1 bin directory is set first in the path:

From codelite's main menu:
Settings -> environment variables

Add this line

```
PATH=/path/to/mingw481/bin;$PATH
```

When running it outside of codelite, simply copy the correct dll next to your executable

Eran

Answer (score 0):

Solved: the problem was in the Windows environment variables: in the "System Properties"->"Environment Variables" (in Windows 7, in my case) both %PATH% variables (the one for your account AND system-wide variable %PATH%) there wasn't the MinGW path (C:\MinGW\bin in my case). 
It wasn't a tinyxml problem: to work properly, just add the tinyxml .cpp files to the workspace and include tinyxml.h in the preprocessor.