# Should we use C functions in std namespace?

Tags: c++, c

I noticed that some C++ textbooks use C functions like `printf` as `std::printf` (include via `<cstdio>` rather than `<stdio.h>`).

However, in most C++ codes I saw in Github (including those written by professional developers), they just use `<stdio.h>` and `printf`. No sane programmer will name his function as `printf` or any famous C-function names anyway as other readers will likely to get confused.

It looks like there is no real benefit of using `std::printf` other than having to type more characters.

Comment: Just varying levels of being pedantic.

Comment: if `printf()` is defined in some other library, including your own, `std::` will indicate you are using the one from `cstdio`:

Comment: I believe this post might explain things a little. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460250/cstdio-stdio-h-namespace

Comment: The C++ standard library (which includes large parts of the C standard library) lives in namespace `std`.

Answer (score 0):

Namespacing in C++ allows for you to define functions that would clash with C functions. Including `cstdio` instead of `stdio.h` and using `std::printf` allows you for having a function called, say `rename` without having it clash with `stdio`'s rename. That's what namespaces are for, actually.

Comment: Except all names from the C standard library are reserved in the global namespace.