# Why does EOF not terminate during my scanf while loop?

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++ and am trying to learn how to use scanf and printf for faster input and output. Here is the code I'm currently working on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int time, record;
    double down, loan;
    while (scanf("%d %lf %lf %d", &time, &down, &loan, &record) != EOF) {
        double value = down + loan;
        double owed = loan;
        double payment = owed/time;

        // current simulated month and depreciation
        int rday, c = 0;
        double temp, dep;
        bool found = false;

        // finds value and owed after records
        while (!found && record > 0) {
            scanf("%d %lf", &rday, &temp);
            // adjusts value and owed to day before listed on record
            while (!found && c <= rday) {
                if (c == rday) {
                    dep = temp;
                }
                value *= 1 - dep;
                if (c > 0) {
                    owed -= payment;
                }
                c++;

                // determines if found date
                if  (owed < value) {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            record--;
        }

        // finds point where owed < value
        while (!found && value < owed) {
            value *= 1 - dep;
            owed -= payment;
            c++;
        }

        if (c - 1 == 1) {
            printf("%d month\n", c - 1);
        }
        else {
            printf("%d months\n", c - 1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this on Code::Blocks, it prints the correct answers, but the outermost while loop doesn't terminate even when I enter `CTRL+Z` (I am using Windows). Here is my input:

```
30 500.0 15000.0 3
0 .10
1 .03
3 .002
12 500.0 9999.99 2
0 .05
2 .1
60 2400.0 30000.0 3
0 .2
1 .05
12 .025
-99 0 17000 1
```

Here is an image of the what happens:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2AWm.png)

I've tried changing the loop condition to `scanf("%d %lf %lf %d", &time, &down, &loan, &record) == 4`, but the same problem happens. Could someone please explain what the issue with my code is?

Comment: ".. learning C++ and am trying to learn how to use scanf and printf for faster"  --> consider learning about streams `<<` and `>>`.  Save `scanf` and `printf` for C.

Comment: Why does code not check the return value of `scanf("%d %lf", &rday, &temp);`?  I suspect this is the source of the "outermost while loop doesn't terminate" as the inner never finished.  Either that or you are not signaling _end-of-file_ correctly.

Comment: Pressing "enter" after "ctrl+z" works? `Ctrl+z` just adds `EOF` to stdin, but `scanf` only process when `enter`is pressed.

Comment: How was it determined that code is not stuck in `while (!found && value < owed)`?

Comment: @chux The input is formatted so that each line with four numbers represents a test case, and each line with two numbers is information used in the calculation. I'm also pretty sure `CTRL+Z` signals EOF. It's worked previously for other programs.

Comment: @Ripi2 I pressed enter after `CTRL+Z`

Comment: nitpick: instead of '#include <stdio.h>' use '#include <cstdio>' See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460250/cstdio-stdio-h-namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions and answers, everyone! I figured out the bug. Kind of embarrassing, but it turns out the issue was with the last line of input.

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```
while (scanf("%d %lf %lf %d", &time, &down, &loan, &record) != EOF)
```

you expect 4 variables to be read into when the read is successful. When `scanf` is able to successfully extract the data from `stdin` for all the arguments, it will return 4. Change the check to use that number.

```
while (scanf("%d %lf %lf %d", &time, &down, &loan, &record) == 4)
```

Comment: I already tried to use that loop condition. The same issue occurs, unfortunately.

Comment: @nullptr, that's strange indeed.

Comment: @nullptr, See http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=19351.0. It says *SOLVED:  After you press ctrl+Z, you have to press enter.  
I am using Windows 7*.

Comment: I pressed enter after `CTRL+Z` every time.

Comment: @nullptr, still no luck?

Comment: Turns out the issue was with the input. I was missing a line with two integers. Thanks for your help, though!

Answer (score 0):

It's because `scanf` never  returns `EOF`, so the termination  condition is never satisfied.

Comment: @CiaPan: Thanks for the reply. Could you clarify what you mean when you say that `scanf` never returns EOF? I checked the documentation on www.cplusplus.com and it says "If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). And, if either happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned."

Comment: From https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf:  *or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.*

Comment: @RSAHU So  I understand you already know the reason: there was some runtime constraint violation, right?

Comment: @CiaPan, the first comment was incorrect. They apply to `scanf_s` family of functions. The new comment applies to `scanf` family of functions.