# Calling C++ standard header (cstdint) from C file

Tags: c++, c, std, mixing

I have an external library written in C++ such as

**external.h**

```
#ifndef OUTPUT_FROM_CPP_H
#define OUTPUT_FROM_CPP_H

#include <cstdint>
extern "C" uint8_t myCppFunction(uint8_t n);

#endif
```

**external.cpp**

```
#include "external.h"
uint8_t myCppFunction(uint8_t n)
{
    return n;
}
```

Currently I have no choice but use this C++ library in my current C project. But my compiler is telling me

```
No such file or director #include <cstdint>
```

when used in my C project

**main.c**

```
#include "external.h"

int main()
{
    int a = myCppFunction(2000);

    return a;
}
```

I understand that this is because **cstdint** is a C++ standard library that I'm trying to use through my C file.

My questions are:

- Is there a way I can manage to use this C++ library in my C project without modifying my libary ?
- If no, what whould I have to do on the library side to make it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `c` prefix in `cstdint` is because it's really a header file incorporated from C. The name in C is `stdint.h`.

You need to conditionally include the correct header by detecting the `__cplusplus` macro. You also need this macro to use the `extern "C"` part, as that's C++ specific:

```
#ifndef OUTPUT_FROM_CPP_H
#define OUTPUT_FROM_CPP_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
// Building with a C++ compiler
# include <cstdint>
extern "C" {
#else
// Building with a C compiler
# include <stdint.h>
#endif

uint8_t myCppFunction(uint8_t n);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}  // Match extern "C"
#endif

#endif
```

Comment: This is the only answer (as I write this) that doesn't either require creation of separate header files for C and C++, and therefore create a long-term maintenance headache where two files have to be kept in sync; or forces C++ code to depend on `stdint.h` instead of `cstdint` - [those two headers are **not** exactly equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460250/cstdio-stdio-h-namespace).

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the library.

Replace `<cstdint>` with `<stdint.h>`. Normally the former is recommended, but only the latter exists in C.

You should also be getting errors on `extern "C"`. That's solved by putting following right below the includes:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

With a matching section at the end of file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Then `extern "C"` can be removed from individual functions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can manage to use this C++ library in my C project without modifying my libary ?

Create a *separate* header that is portable with C and use that header when compiling with C compiler:

```
// external_portable_with_c.h
// rewrite by hand or generate from original external.h
// could be just sed 's/cstdint/stdint.h/; s/extern "C"//'
#include <stdint.h>
uint8_t myCppFunction(uint8_t n);
 
// c_source_file.c
#include "external_portable_with_c.h"
void func() {
    myCppFunction(1);
}
```

> If no, what whould I have to do on the library side to make it possible ?

Is answered by other answers. Protect the C++ parts with `#ifdef __cplusplus`.

Note that (some? all?) compilers *require* the `main` function to be compiled with C++ compiler for C++ and C to work together properly. https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#overview-mixing-langs

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the library header, create a new file, for example `includes_for_cpp/cstdint` with content

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

Add the directory `includes_for_cpp` to the include path of your C project. After that, `#include <cstdint>` should find your file.